# Resolve hostname of a Centos 6.5 dedicated server with a FQDN registered with Godddy

Tags: centos, nameserver, godaddy

I have a domain registered with Godaddy and I am setting up a dedicated server for learning purposes. I want the server's hostname to be resolvable. I created custom NS records (ns1.mydomain.com & ns2.mydomain.com) with Godaddy pointing to my server ip. I edited the /etc/hosts files and /etc/sysconfig/network to use the hostname abc.mydomain.com. But I am unable to resolve the hostname to ip address. Please help me step by step considering I am a total noob.

Comment: Is your server running a DNS server?  It would probably be easiest to leave the NS records pointed to GoDaddy, and then use the Go Daddy domain management interface to setup the DNS entry for `abc.mydomain.com` to point to your server.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is where I need help. I am now pointing the domain to godaddy default nameservers but I don't know how to follow further steps.

Comment: Personally not a fan of Go Daddy but could you link to the steps you are having issues with (support / faq links used) so maybe one of us here can better explain them or  walk you through as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to have a resolvable hostname without having to install & configure a DNS server on your box you should use GD DNS servers. (not a fan of GD either btw)

So instead of pointing your domain to ns1.yourdomain.com & ns2.yourdomain.com point your domain to GD nameservers and add hostname A record. The steps of adding an A record are outlined here: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names